# Mod_rewrite in Azure

Tags: .htaccess, azure

I was write simple .htaccess and test it on Windows Azure Web Sites, but mod_rewrite didn't work there. Why? How I can reconfigurate my Azure?

RewriteEngine on
AddDefaultCharset utf-8

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteRule ^test.html$ test.php?%{QUERY_STRING} [L]

Answer (score 17, accepted):

`.htaccess` file is not recognizible by Azure Web Sites.

Azure Web Sites run on Microsoft IIS.

IIS has a URL Rewrite module, very similar to mod_rewrite for Apache. You can configure URL Rewrite rules by having a `web.config` file in your site root folder.

Follow the [Creating Rewrite Rules](http://www.iis.net/learn/extensions/url-rewrite-module/creating-rewrite-rules-for-the-url-rewrite-module) article and scroll down to the "View the rule in Config file" to get an idea what it looks like.

Your rules defined, will look like this in `web.config` (and will most probably work as expected):

```
<rewrite>
    <rules>
        <rule name="Imported Rule 1" stopProcessing="true">
            <match url="^test.html$" ignoreCase="false" />
            <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
                <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" ignoreCase="false" negate="true" />
                <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" ignoreCase="false" negate="true" />
            </conditions>
            <action type="Rewrite" url="test.php?{QUERY_STRING}" appendQueryString="false" />
        </rule>
    </rules>
</rewrite>
```

Comment: The Microsoft "URL Rewrite" module for IIS also includes a tool for converting mod_rewrite rules to the IIS format. The module is freely available, but it is not part of the Windows install. It can be downloaded: https://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/url-rewrite Installing that adds "URL Rewrite" to IIS manager. Open that one and use the "Import rules" action to convert. Detailed instructions: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/extensions/url-rewrite-module/importing-apache-modrewrite-rules