# How to configure Multiple Azure websites on Single Domain name

Tags: asp.net, azure, azure-web-roles, azure-web-app-service

I have azure websites like

```
validation.azurewebsites.net
config.azurewebsites.net
```

I have domain name `www.mydomainname.com` which is nothing but my main azure website
`mydomainname.azurewebsites.net`

I want to configure Url in a way like

```
www.mydomainname.com/validation
www.mydomainname.com/config
```

url `www.mydomainname.com/validation` will redirect to azurewebsite `validation.azurewebsites.net`
and 
url `www.mydomainname.com/config` will redirect to azurewebsite `config.azurewebsites.net`

I tried many things like `CNAME` configuration `Manage domain` but did not able to achieve this.
any clue?

Comment: Does Azure support `mod_rewrite`? If not, `.htaccess` should be untagged.

Comment: Removing `.htaccess` tag per [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17833260/1626250).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If all you want to do is redirection to an Azure web site, then you should be able to use the built-in UrlRewrite functionality which is available in Azure webapps. The only thing you need to do is add the below section in web.config for your Azure Webapp `mydomainname.azurewebsites.net` under the `<system.webServer>` section and the redirection should happen for the two scenarios you mentioned

```
<rewrite>
        <rules>
            <rule name="redirectToValidation" patternSyntax="Wildcard" stopProcessing="true">
                <match url="*" />
                <action type="Redirect" url="http://validation.azurewebsites.net/" appendQueryString="false" redirectType="Found" />
                <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAny">
                    <add input="{PATH_INFO}" pattern="/validation/*" />
                    <add input="{PATH_INFO}" pattern="/validation" />
                </conditions>
            </rule>
             <rule name="redirectToConfig" patternSyntax="Wildcard" stopProcessing="true">
                <match url="*" />
                <action type="Redirect" url="http://config.azurewebsites.net/" appendQueryString="false" redirectType="Found" />
                <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAny">
                    <add input="{PATH_INFO}" pattern="/config/*" />
                    <add input="{PATH_INFO}" pattern="/config" />
                </conditions>
            </rule>
        </rules>
    </rewrite>
```

There may be better ways of configuring URL Rewrite rules so see what exactly you need and configure the URL-REWRITE rule accordingly.

Comment: thanks a lot but in above solution URL is also changes :(  when i enter url `www.mydomainname.com/config` it is going to changed to  `config.azurewebsites.net` , How can I do this routing internally . I want Url should be displayed like `www.mydomainname.com/config` which internally calls `config.azurewebsites.net`

Comment: For sure it will, I thought that is what you wanted :) ....

So basically what you are trying to do is setup an Azure webapp as a REVERSE proxy scenario. Check this blog from Ruslan as it details exactly on how to do that - http://ruslany.net/2014/05/using-azure-web-site-as-a-reverse-proxy/  You might have to change the URLREWRITE configuration a bit to match your scenario but that blog should give you a good start....

Comment: thanks but still using blog post also i'm uable to achieve my scenario :( as it is not mention where to write my other 2 website urls?

Comment: Not sure if I understood the question...in his blog he talks showed redirection to www.iis.net, you need to change that to your azuresites.net URL. Are you able to get one site rediection to work first ?

Comment: he has not shown any steps to how to configure redirected websites ? (he has not described where and how to configure even 1 site redirection)

Answer (score 1):

You probably already have this setup, but here is what I do.

I do this by setting up a `VirtualApplication` in a cloud service project.  The main reason is because I then only have to pay for one cloud service instead of multiple web applications.  Here is a link to a tutorial that walks through this:

https://michaelcollier.wordpress.com/2013/01/14/multiple-sites-in-a-web-role/