# .htaccess file completely ignored

Tags: .htaccess, azure

I'm trying to setup HTTP authentication to protect my site. The site is hosted with Azure.

```
AuthType Basic
AuthName "Protected Area"
AuthUserFile D:\\home\\site\\wwwroot/.htpasswd
Require valid-user

# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

This is being completely ignored. To test further I deleted my .htaccess altogether and my site still works fine. It is being completely ignored.

Comment: Are you using apache?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please see the following link: [Mod_rewrite in Azure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17832840/mod-rewrite-in-azure)

.htaccess is not read by Azure websites. You must create your rules in your web.config file

If you want to use an .htaccess file you would need to stand up a Linux VM with apache and go that route.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Please also see this article that explains exactly how to convert your rules over: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/azureossds/archive/2015/04/23/converting-apache-htaccess-rules-to-web-config-using-iis-manager-for-azure-and-iis-websites.aspx