# How avoid access images from folder Codeigniter Hosted in Azure web hosting

Tags: php, codeigniter, azure, web-config, codeigniter-3

My folder structure is like this.

```
application
system
public
uploads > images
index.php
----------
```

I want to **restrict** access the images in uploads folder from non-users by typing path in URL **(Ex - www.exapmple.com/uploads/images/new.png )**. My hosting is Azure, I think it dosen't support .htaccess also.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17832840/mod-rewrite-in-azure

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added below code to uploads folder as web.config (because of .htaccess files are not working in Azure hosting). After that I converted all images to **base64** **encoding**. For the image views I used **base64 decoding**. From this solution I solved my problem easily.

```
<location path="Admin">
    <system.web>
        <authorization>
            <allow roles="Administrator"/>
            <deny users="*"/>
        </authorization>
    </system.web>
</location>
```

Answer (score 0):

Azure uses IIS to host your web app. So to achieve your requirement, you can first add IIS configuration file named `web.config` under the `/wwwroot` folder, then add the following element into `<system.webServer>`.

```
<security>
  <requestFiltering>
    <hiddenSegments>
      <add segment="uploads"/>
    </hiddenSegments>
  </requestFiltering>
</security>
```

Finally the `web.config` will be something that looks like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
  <system.webServer>

    <security>
      <requestFiltering>
        <hiddenSegments>
          <add segment="uploads" />
        </hiddenSegments>
      </requestFiltering>
    </security>

  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

This will prevent all users from direct access to `/uploads` folder and its content.

---

### Edit:

You can use *Virtual Directory* to show images in upload folder to public.

**Step by Step**

1. In the [Azure Portal](https://ms.portal.azure.com), open the blade for the web app.
2. Click on **Application settings** under SETTINGS menu.
3. Scroll to **Virtual applications and directories**.
4. Add a **Virtual Directory** `/public`, then enter **Physical path** `site\wwwroot\uploads\images`.
5. Click **Save**.

Here is the picture:

[image]

Now you can type the path in URL `www.exapmple.com/public/new.png` to access the image which actually locates under `site\wwwroot\uploads\images` folder.

Comment: Thank you for your reply Aaron. But my problem is,I want to show images in upload folder to public. (users and non users) Any of user not able to direct access the image from URL. With your solution I cant show image to public. Is there any possible way to block direct access the images in upload folder by URL instead of system retrieve the image?? I think you can understand my situation!